# Get the repeated values of the first character in a string

Tags: php, strpos

I have a strings similar to this one,

```
$string = "01110111011101110111101110111110111111";
```

I need to get the first character in the string (in this case, 0). I then need to get the positions of all the occurrences of that character in the string. All the occurrences should be put into an array with the first element being 1 (the first occurrence is the first character of the string).

For example, the above string should produce an array like this,

```
$return_value = array([0]=>1, [1]=>5, [2]=>9, [3]=>13, [4]=> 17....);
```

Comment: Please say it clearly. I cannot understand your question.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply                                                                                
How can i get repeated character first & last position

$string = "011101110111";

Out put like :
$first_position_values = array([0]=>1, [1]=>5, [3]=>9);
$last_position_values  = array([0]=>3, [1]=>7, [3]=>11);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick,

```
$string = "01110111011101110111101110111110111111";
$offset = 0;
$return_value = array();
$character = substr($string, 0, 1);

while (($offset = strpos($string, $character, $offset))!== false) {
    $return_value[] = $offset + 1;
    $offset = $offset + strlen($character);
}

var_dump($return_value);
```

Which return_value will produce,

```
array(8) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(5) [2]=> int(9) [3]=> int(13) [4]=> int(17) [5]=> int(22) [6]=> int(26) [7]=> int(32)}
```

Comment: @Odyssey - Thank u sir

Comment: @PHP No problem, [please mark this as the selected answer](https://i.imgur.com/NqBB71W.png) if it did the job, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer, I hope it will help you.

```
$string = "01110111011101110111101110111110111111";
$return_value = array();
$select = 0;                       //Select value you want to find
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++)
{
    if($string[$i] == $select) $return_value[] = $i + 1;   //Get the position in string
}
var_dump($return_value);

Result
array(8) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(5) [2]=> int(9) [3]=> int(13) [4]=> int(17) [5]=> int(22) [6]=> int(26) [7]=> int(32) }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution: split the string into characters then run through the list and register when the current character changes.

When it changes from `0` to `1` it is a start: remember the current position; when it changes from `1` to `0` it is an end: remember the previous position (the position of the last `1`).

```
$string = "01110111011101110111101110111110111111";

// The current character
// Used also as index in $positions (0 => starts, 1 => ends)
// And also used to adjust the stored position: 
// ends are 1 character less that the current position
$current = '0';
// Collect starts and ends here ([0] => starts, [1] => ends)
$positions = array(array(), array());
// The current position in string; start before the first character
$pos = -1;
// Split the string to characters
foreach (str_split($string) as $digit) {
    // Advance to the current position in string
    $pos ++;
    // When the current character changes...
    if ($digit != $current) {
        // ... put the position in the appropriate list
        $positions[$current][] = $pos - $current;
    }
    // Update current character
    $current = $digit;
}
// If the last digit was a '1' then it is an (unrecorded) end
if ($current == '1') {
    // There is no need to adjust, $pos is strlen($string)-1
    $positions[$current][] = $pos;
}

// Dump the result
echo("start: ". implode(', ', $positions[0])."\n");
echo("end  : ". implode(', ', $positions[1])."\n");
```